# Local storage dont support icon class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using sembast database for local storage and sembast dont support icon class its nosql database but i don't think it will change anything as far as I know sqlflite dont support too. i need to storage my icons and call back so i tried like save:

```
    String myicon = 'Icons.add'; // in db
    ...
    actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(myicon),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
```

its not working *icon cant be string and i couldnt convert string to icon so I'd be happy if someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a Map to reference the IconData... then you will store the String in your DB.

```
  Map<String, IconData> myIcons = { 
      'add' : Icons.add, 
      'edit' : Icons.edit, 
  };

  String iconString = 'add'; // in db
  ...
  actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(myIcons[iconString]),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
  ],
```